# Classifying points in accordance with their coordinates

Tags: performance, matlab, sorting, grouping, classification

`A` is a coordinate matrix of several points in 3D (x,y,z). For instance:

`A= [1.6 2.13 3; 1.2 2.36 5; 1.4 2.4 6; 1.01 2.21 9]`

`A =
    1.6     2.13     3.0
    1.2     2.36     5.0
    1.4     2.40     6.0
    1.01    2.21     9.0`

I am looking for a "efficient" solution for grouping points with respect to the second column (`Y`) into "three" groups with threshold of `0.09`. means:

`GroupNumber = 3;
threshold = (max(A(:,2))-min(A(:,2)))/GroupNumber;`

`Group{1} = 
    1.60    2.13    3.0
    1.01    2.21    9.00
Group{2} =
    1.2     2.36    5.0
Group{3} =
    1.4     2.40    6.0`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why 2.36 and 2.40 are not in the same group? You can use k-nearest neighbor classification method to achieve that result easily.

Comment: @NKN Thanks for your response. You were right. The question has been amended.

Comment: You mean `0.09` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach #1

For `A` with decent number of rows in it, you might prefer a vectorized solution -

```
GroupNumber = 3;

sorted_A = sortrows(A,2);
sorted_A_col2 = sorted_A(:,2);

limits = sorted_A_col2 + (max(sorted_A_col2) - sorted_A_col2)./GroupNumber;
matches = bsxfun(@le,sorted_A_col2,limits.'); %//'

[~,col_ind] = max(matches,[],2);
groups = arrayfun(@(x) sorted_A(col_ind == x,:), unique(col_ind),'Uniform',0);
```

Display output with `celldisp(groups)` for given input -

```
groups{1} =
    1.6000    2.1300    3.0000
    1.0100    2.2100    9.0000
groups{2} =
    1.2000    2.3600    5.0000
groups{3} =
    1.4000    2.4000    6.0000
```

---

### Approach #2

For `A` with enormously huge  number of rows in it, you most likely won't have memory left to work with `bsxfun` and you would be forced to use some sort of loopy approach for such a case and therefore won't be very efficient. The following could be one of those -

```
GroupNumber = 3;

sorted_A = sortrows(A,2);
sorted_A_col2 = sorted_A(:,2);
limits = sorted_A_col2 + (max(sorted_A_col2) - sorted_A_col2)./GroupNumber;

nrows = size(A,1);
prev_matches = false(nrows,1);
groups = cell(nrows,1);
for iter = 1:nrows
    curr_matches = sorted_A_col2<=limits(iter);
    groups{iter} = sorted_A(xor(curr_matches,prev_matches),:);
    prev_matches = curr_matches;
end
groups = groups(~cellfun('isempty',groups));
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar for your time as always!
Although, the proposed approach looks great, it would give an error for a large set of data (like 2,000,000 Points) at `bsxfun` line:
`Error using bsxfun;
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options`

I did in another way which I am writing below. BTW, I will appreciate it, if you correct me ;)

Comment: @Iman Sorry! This one left my mind for some reason, but I am glad to get back to it. So, check out the edited codes?

Comment: sorry for my late response, your code seems better organized and more efficient. I selected as a right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have no access to MATLAB now, but roughly it would be something like this:

You can get the first group as follows,

```
A= [1.6 2.13 3; 1.2 2.36 5; 1.4 2.4 6; 1.01 2.21 9]
B = A(:,2);
mean = (max(B)-min(B))/3;
C = B - min(B);
Group1 = A(C<mean,:)
```

then make the new matrix from the remaining rows as follows

```
A = A(C>=mean,:)
```

and then repeat until `isempty(A) == true`. There are many optimizations possible though.

**Edit:**

```
A= [1.6 2.13 3; 1.2 2.36 5; 1.4 2.4 6; 1.01 2.21 9]
while ~isempty(A)
    B = A(:,2);
    mean1 = (max(B)-min(B))/3;
    C = B - min(B);
    Group1 = A(C<mean1,:)
    A = A(C>=mean1,:)
    if size(A,1)==1
        break;
    end
end
```

The result would be:

```
A =

   1.6000   2.1300   3.0000
   1.2000   2.3600   5.0000
   1.4000   2.4000   6.0000
   1.0100   2.2100   9.0000

Group1 =

   1.6000   2.1300   3.0000
   1.0100   2.2100   9.0000

A =

   1.2000   2.3600   5.0000
   1.4000   2.4000   6.0000

Group1 =

   1.2000   2.3600   5.0000

A =

   1.4000   2.4000   6.0000
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. However, let's leave the question open for a while to receive some more possible answer.

Answer (score -1):

Generating a large set of data:

```
  A = 100 * rand(2000000,3);
    tic 
    GroupNumber = 100 ;` `% in hundred group
    Threshold = (length(A))/GroupNumber ;
    A = sortrows(A,2);
    Group = cell(GroupNumber,1);`

        for i = 1 : GroupNumber;

              if i == 1
           Group{i} = A(1:ceil(Threshold),:);     

           elseif i > 1 && i~= GroupNumber 
               if ceil((i-1)*Threshold) == ceil(Threshold)
                   bottum = ceil((i-1)*Threshold)+1;
               else
               end
               top=ceil(i*Threshold);
           Group{i} = A(bottum:top,:);

           elseif i == GroupNumber
               bottum = ceil((i-1)*Threshold);
               if ceil((i-1)*Threshold)<=ceil(i*Threshold) && ceil((i-1)*Threshold)>top

                   Group{i} = A(bottum:end,:);
               elseif  ceil((i-1)*Threshold)<=top

                   Group{i} = A(bottum+1:end,:);
               end

         end  
 end

    toc
```

Elapsed time is **`1.160457`** seconds.

and for proposed set of data it is like:

```
A = [1.6 2.13 3; 1.2 2.36 5; 1.4 2.4 6; 1.01 2.21 9];
GroupNumber = 3;

Group{1} =
     1.6000    2.1300    3.0000
     1.0100    2.2100    9.0000
Group{2} =
     1.2000    2.3600    5.0000 
Group{3} =
     1.4000    2.4000    6.0000
```

Elapsed time is **`0.000010`** seconds.

Comment: @Divakar I know the last presented approach is not an optimized solution. But, do you think that it is an acceptable answer?

Comment: Don't think this would give you correct results. For verfifcation, you can try with a smaller `A` like `A = rand(20,3);` and use `GroupNumber = 3` and compare against either of my two listed approaches?